# How to download Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

It seems like they have changed their web-page and I can no longer find the binary distributions. The main website is http://tomcat.apache.org/.

Selecting ie. Tomcat 8 on the left hand side under the download section redirects me to http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi.

Then clicking on the suggested mirror just lists a bunch of different folders like /abdera, /accumulo, /ace, /activemg...

Where can I find a normal Tomcat 8 .zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download from either of the below links

1. [Tomcat 8.0.45](http://apache.mirror.amaze.com.au/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.45/bin/)
2. [Tomcat 8.5.16](http://apache.mirror.amaze.com.au/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/)

Please put some effort to browse and find details..
The link apache.mirror Url is the mirror for all the downloads under Apache Project .

Comment: Lecturing somebody while answering a question that has nothing to do on SO (instead of requesting a close) is ballsy, I must say.